# Nested function call scoping and syntax

Tags: perl, syntax, recursion, scope

I'm attempting to call a nested recursive perl function, but I can't tack the correct syntax.

**Question**: What is the correct syntax to perform a recursive call for a nested function (if nested functions should be recursively called at all)?

**Answer: Refer to suggested pseudocode in the accepted answer.**

Here is a pseudocode snippet:

```
use Scalar::Util;
sub outerfunction {
  my $innerfunction = sub {
    # Do something
    innerfunction(); 
    # Do other things
  }; 
  Scalar::Util::weaken($innerfunction); 
  &$innerfunction(@_);
};
```

I've tried to invoke innerfunction as the following (with the consequential error messages):

```
innerfunction
```

> Undefined subroutine &main::innerfunction

```
&innerfunction
```

> Undefined subroutine &main::innerfunction

```
&$innerfunction
```

> Global symbol "$innerfunction" requires explicit package name

I've also tried to declare the innerfunction as local, but receive the following:

> Global symbol "$innerfunction" requires explicit package name

I don't have much experience with interpreted languages, so any incidental commentary related to memory/stack leakage/ corruption or other dangers with the above pseudocode (other than system limits on recursion) would be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks!
perl v5.10.1 running on Linux 2.6.34.7-61.fc13.x86_64

Comment: What do you intend by using `weaken` on the reference?

Comment: And why do you use nested functions? What do you think the benefit is?

Comment: Came across a few postings that suggested its usage to prevent memory leakage from obsolete references that the perl interpreter may overlook when the function reference goes out of scope. It does not appear to affect the underlying problem, though. Please correct my understanding if the use of weaken() is inadvisable.

Comment: I largely use the nested function to preserve memory allocation and contain the code for a specific purpose to this subroutine (the function is passed to a remote machine for execution, so it is easier to pass a single function instead of several functions -- though the problem is not insurmountable). Though, as stated, I do not have a substantial grasp of the perl interpreter behavior and its memory management subsystem -- so please let me know if there is no benefit to doing so. I can extract the function to the global scope if needed, but was curious if an alternate solution exists.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimisation. Do you have problems with memory leaks? I would think that something as basic as subroutines are fairly well protected against leakage.

Comment: Perhaps - it is done out of an abundance of caution as I don't have much experience with perl and it'll be difficult to identify and troubleshoot memory leaks as the function will execute across several different platforms and perl interpreter versions as part of a Condor pool.

Comment: @TLP, the `weaken` is necessary when creating a recursive closure.  If the closure holds a strong reference to itself, then it can never be garbage collected (until the interpreter shuts down).  It may not be a serious leak (that depends on how often `outerfunction` is called), but it will be a memory leak.

Comment: @cjm But is it a better solution in regards to memory leaks? Would using a regular sub cause memory leaks?

Comment: @TLP, `my $foo; sub foo { $foo } $foo = \&foo;` does suffer from the same problem (i.e. `$foo` and `&foo` won't get freed until global destruction), but 1) you'd never do that, and 2) `foo` doesn't go out of scope until global destruction anyway so it's moot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `innerfunction()` syntax is only available for subroutines that have been installed into the symbol table (such as the `sub NAME {...}` syntax does).  You need to call your inner function as `$innerfunction->()` or `&$innerfunction()`, but where you are having trouble is with the scoping of the `$innerfunction` lexical.

When you declare a variable with `my`, the variable is in scope **after** that statement ends.  So you need to split your declaration:

```
 my $innerfunction;
    $innerfunction = sub {
        ...
        $innerfunction->();
        ...
    };
```

To break the circular reference with `weaken` the usual pattern is:

```
use Scalar::Util;
sub outer_function {
    my $weak_ref;
    $weak_ref = my $strong_ref = sub {
        # Do something
        $weak_ref->(); 
        # Do other things
    };
    Scalar::Util::weaken($weak_ref); 
    return $strong_ref;
};
```

So now, as soon as `$strong_ref` goes out of scope, the subroutine will be garbage collected.

Comment: Have you played with the new `__SUB__` feature in *blead* yet?

Answer (score 4):

```
sub outer_function {
    local *inner_function = sub {
        # Do something
        inner_function(); 
        # Do other things
    };
    inner_function();
};
```

is almost as good as the following, yet much much clearer:

```
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );
sub outer_function {
    my $weak_ref;
    my $strong_ref = sub {
        # Do something
        $weak_ref->(); 
        # Do other things
    };
    weaken($weak_ref = $strong_ref);  # Avoid memory leak.
    $strong_ref->();
};
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the top version does NOT suffer from a memory leak even though it doesn't go through all those contortions. The `local` provides the same service as the `weaken`. (@Eric Strom might find this interesting.)

Comment: I agree that using `local` is cleaner, but the utility is far reduced.  The strength of a lexical closure is that it can be returned (as my answer shows).  If you try to return the coderef from your first example and then called it, at best you would get a fatal error about calling an undefined subroutine, and at worst you would call an unrelated but like named subroutine, leading to all sorts of unintended behavior.  I made the assumption in my answer that the OP was just showing a short example and wanted to use the coderef in outer scopes.  If not, then I agree that `local` works well.

Comment: Re "but the utility is far reduced", I've done "millions" of recursive functions that way and none with weaken, so it's not reduced much. Re "as my answer shows", yes, I noticed you deviated from the question somewhat. Most recursive functions can benefit from a non-recursive wrapper, in which case the recursive part itself should ideally be private. It's not a question of creating a closure.